# How to use .Net Ajax Accordion to show Short Description to Long

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm a newbie at ASP and Ajax, Please I want to use Accordion Tool from Ajax Control Toolkit, to show a short and long description text.

thanks

Comment: actually what have you tried? could you post something you don't understand ? if you newbie as you said, please refer to : http://www.ajaxtutorials.com/controls/ajax-accordion-control-tutorial-asp-net-4-0/

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. thank you for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Accordion Tutorial</title>
    <style type="text/css">  
        .accordion {  
            width: 400px;  
        }  

        .accordionHeader {  
            border: 1px solid #2F4F4F;  
            color: white;  
            background-color: #2E4d7B;  
            font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;  
            font-size: 12px;  
            font-weight: bold;  
            padding: 5px;  
            margin-top: 5px;  
            cursor: pointer;  
        }  

        .accordionHeaderSelected {  
            border: 1px solid #2F4F4F;  
            color: white;  
            background-color: #5078B3;  
            font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;  
            font-size: 12px;  
            font-weight: bold;  
            padding: 5px;  
            margin-top: 5px;  
            cursor: pointer;  
        }  

        .accordionContent {  
            background-color: #D3DEEF;  
            border: 1px dashed #2F4F4F;  
            border-top: none;  
            padding: 5px;  
            padding-top: 10px;  
        }  
    </style>  
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <div>
            <asp:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server"
                SelectedIndex="0"
    HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
    HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected"
    ContentCssClass="accordionContent"
    AutoSize="None"
    FadeTransitions="true"
    TransitionDuration="250"
    FramesPerSecond="40"
    RequireOpenedPane="false"
    SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true" Height="367px" Width="540px">

    <Panes>  
    <asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane1" runat="server">  
        <Header>Pane 1</Header>  
        <Content> 
             This is pane 1 
        </Content>  
    </asp:AccordionPane>  
    <asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane2" runat="server">  
        <Header>Pane 2</Header>  
        <Content>  
             This is pane 2
       </Content>  
    </asp:AccordionPane>  
    <asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane3" runat="server">  
        <Header>Pane 3</Header>  
        <Content>
            This is pane 3  
        </Content>  
    </asp:AccordionPane>  
</Panes>  

       </asp:Accordion>



        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you please go through the link

http://www.ajaxtutorials.com/controls/ajax-accordion-control-tutorial-asp-net-4-0/

And this is the documentation provided by Ajax
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Accordion/Accordion.aspx

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.